# Spring custom annotation for bean injection

Tags: spring, kotlin, annotations, factory

I am looking to inject a bean by means of a custom annotation

```
@Service
class Foo(@MyBean val bar: Bar) { fun someMethod() { bar.invoke() } }
```

with

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class MyBean
```

Currently we have a configuration class that defines multiple bean methods

```
@Configuration
class config {
    @Bean 
    fun bar(): Bar = { getBaz() }
}
```

I have seen implementations of `BeanPostProcessor` but that seems to add behaviour to already existing beans. My question is, is there a way to initialise and assign beans to a field by means of a custom annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're injecting the field through a constructor, you don't need to annotate the field itself, but rather the constructor.